# Decide if $y(u,t)$ a zero-mean random process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random

A communication signal $x(u,t)$ is transmitted to a receiver, which, because of two distinct paths of transmission, observes the received signal $y(u,t)$: $y(u,t) = x(u,t) + c x(u,t-t_m), t \in (-\infty, \infty)$, where $c$ and $t_m$ have known constant values in the range $|c| < 1$ and $t_m > 0$. The random process $x(u,t)$ is a wide-sense stationary (WSS) Gaussian random process with known power spectral density (PSD)
$$
S_X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
P & \text{for } 0 \leq \omega \leq 4\pi, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Is $y(u,t)$ a zero-mean random process?

---

The following is my try:
$$
\begin{align}
E[y(u, t)]
& = E[x(u, t) + c x(u, t - t_m)] \\
& = E[x(u, t)] + c E[x(u, t - t_m)].
\end{align}
$$
Then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Note that $E[x(u,t)]=0, ~t\in \mathbb{R}, u$.

Comment: I don't know why $E[x(u,t)]=0$, could you please teach me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Any finite linear combination of variables $x(u,t)$ is centered Gaussian.

Comment: Why is any finite linear combination of variables $x(u,t)$ is centered Gaussian? Could you please teach me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a question about the parameter $u$, what is?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: The last statement should be derived from the definition of Gaussian random process.